# Django 502 bad gateway with Nginx and Uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, web, uwsgi

I can normally open up my web in the front several hours after deployment,but later , it occurred 502 bad gateway ,it is so wired, my web uses Django and Nginx and Uwsgi, i do research a lot on google,but failed with nothing

Here is my configuration:

**1.Nginx configuration**

```
# mysite_nginx.conf


upstream django {


server 127.0.0.1:8004; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}


server {

listen      80;

server_name www.example.com  # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
charset     utf-8;


client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste


location /media  {
    alias /home/blender_font_project/django_file/Blender_website/media;  
}

location /static {
    alias /home/blender_font_project/django_file/Blender_website/static; 
}



location / {


    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8003;
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; 
}
}
```

**2.uwsgi configuration**

```
# mysite_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /home/blender_font_project/django_file/Blender_website

module          = djangoTest5.wsgi

master          = true

processes       = 10

socket          = :8003

vacuum          = true
harakiri=60
daemonize=/home/blender_font_project/uwsgi_file/real3dfont_logfile
```

**3.this is my Nginx error log**

```
231 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

BTW , i have set Django to DEBUG Ture and i can access my resource by `www.example.com/static/example.jpg`,but the web page shows 502

I really dont know why , thanks if you offer any help!

Comment: Investigate nginx, uwsgi, django logs.

Comment: i forget to add error log , and i have added,but still in misery

Comment: location / {
 include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; 
 uwsgi_pass http://django;
}

Comment: @Atul Mishra ,do you mean replace that ip with "django" ?if it is ,it failed after i tried

Comment: @Super-ilad Does the file `/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params` exist?

Comment: @xyres yes ,it certainly exists

Comment: Well, Yes - Something like http:// django.

Comment: Well, The problem seems obvious. You can first see the if django is working with uwsgi. In the terminal: $> uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini. Run it to see if any error with this command.

Comment: well,failed with so-called "exit-code",and shows invalid host in upstream when i initiate Nginx

Comment: And Instead of uwsgi_pass. Do proxy_pass

Comment: @Atul Mishra, Great thanks , i love you very much , it is the matter of Django itself, i would have expected a classical Django error html with DEBUG False, but no , so i mistakelly think it is the issue of Nginx !Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(...After million years struggle and strive,with inspiration from a super hero in comment named @Atul Mishra , i finally figure it out...)

It is the matter Django itself,i forget to download mysql module in View , i would have expect a Django error html if it is the django problem, but no , so i mistakenly attribute it to Nginx or Uwsgi

But the wired thing is that Django should have report the error , but no ! what an irresponsible dude!!

so , **1.remember to add Django error log function ,it saves your life** , and

**2.test Django with runserver before Nginx enter the stage even when comet is striking the earth!!**